# How to lock the token, Based on the time in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, token, access-token

Am using the following program for generate the Token,based on the time(current time).It was work properly,It means the token will be generate.

```
         public string GenerateToken()
            {
                MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
                DateTime input = DateTime.Now;
                byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input.ToString());
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
```

And I use the following program for try to lock(expire) the token with in 2 minutes.It means I access the `GetToken() method`, It will return the token for `particular Time(current Time)`.I need to set  valid time 2 minutes for that token.Incase I access the getToken() before 2 minutes I need to get the same token.But I access the `getToken()` after the 2 minutes i need to get new token. How can I do this?How do lock the token?

```
     public string GetToken()
        {
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;               
            tokenExp = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2);
            if (tokenExp >= currentTime)
            {
                token = GenerateToken();
                return token;
            }

            else lock (tokenLock)
                {
                    if (tokenExp >= currentTime)
                    {
                        token = GenerateToken();
                        //return token;

                    }
                    return token;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using something like below in GenerateToken method

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
 dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(-dateTime.Second);
 if (dateTime.Minute % 2 != 0)
     dateTime = dateTime.AddMinutes(1);
```

This will generate time with even minutes which is same for 2 minutes duration.

**UPDATE**

Full Code

```
public string GenerateToken()
{
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(-dateTime.Second);
    if (dateTime.Minute % 2 != 0)
        dateTime = dateTime.AddMinutes(1);

    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dateTime.ToString());
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I try to generate lock the token in GetToken()

Comment: No need to acquire any lock. Modify your GenerateToken method to use the dateTime as shown above. What it would do is, the dateTime will change once in two mins and not every second / minute.

Comment: can u edit that GenerateToken()
 code and post back.because am not able to get your point.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **hashing** while you should use **encryption**.

Hashing is one-way but encryption is two way i.e. when you get back the token, you can decrypt the token to get the original value to be able to calculate time difference and check if it is > 2 minutes.

You can use AES, 3DES, ...

Comment: Encryption and hashing are used to generate the token only .correct?how it was related the lock the token?

Comment: Your locking implementation is not practical - design needs to change. My answer might not answer your question but I am trying to point you in the right direction.